# Compare two PCollections for removal

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Every day latest data available in the CloudSQL table, so while writing data into another CloudSQL table, I need to compare the existing data and perform the actions like, remove the deleted data and update the existing data and insert new data.

Could you please suggest best way to do this scenario using Dataflow pipeline (preferable Java).

One thing I identified that using upsert function in CloudSQL, we could do the insert/update the records with the help of jdbc.JdbcIO. But I do not know how to identified collection for removal.

Comment: can you add some detail to your question? What operation are you exactly doing from table A to B?

Comment: Lets assume Employee information, which is comes from source database table. Every day latest employee information will come to the table, like email, address and etc. Need to compare the existing data before writing the latest employee information into that table(insert or update). If the employee record not present in the latest collection then assume that employee is terminated and need to remove that data from the existing database table while writing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read the old and new tables and do a [Join](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.16.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/joinlibrary/Join.html) followed by a DoFn that compares the two and only outputs changed elements, which can then be written wherever you like.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Idea works good for me. First step used "upsert" function for insert/update the records then used Leftouter Join with that two PCollections (Latest Vs Old) and in ParDo got the removal value records. Finally deleted it.